# Getting "TypeError: object is not a function" when using supertest/superagent in forEach loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, supertest, superagent

I'm using supertest to test a set of URLs by the same rules.

```
var urls = [
    "https://www.example.com",
    "https://www.example2.com"
];

urls.forEach(function (url) {
    console.log('begin');
    request = request(url)
        .get('')
        .expect(200)
        .end(function (err, res) {
            // Check for something
        });
    console.log('end');
});
```

When there is only 1 URL in the array, it works just fine. If I add a 2nd one, however, it fails with the output:

```
begin
end
begin

file.js:11
request = request(json)
^
TypeError: object is not a function
```

My guess is that I can't have 1 instance of supertest running twice, but I can't seem to find a solution to work around this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because your assignment `request = request(url)` overrides the request function.

```
var urls = [
    "https://www.example.com",
    "https://www.example2.com"];

urls.forEach(function (url) {
    console.log('begin');
    var r = request(url)
        .get('')
        .expect(200)
        .end(function (err, res) {
        // Check for something
    });
    console.log('end');
});
```

In the first iteration `request` is referring to a global function but when the `request = request(url)` statement is evaluated the value of `request` is changed as the value returned by `request(url)` so in the second iteration `request` is no longer the function you were expecting it to be.

Answer (score 0):

Change the following

```
request = request(url)
    .get('')
    .expect(200)
    .end(function (err, res) {
        // Check for something
    });
```

to

```
requestVariable = request(url)
    .get('')
    .expect(200)
    .end(function (err, res) {
        // Check for something
    });
```

Comment: Anytime, though I was 2 minutes late :)